# ¿try + except o if + else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy escribiendo unas funciones en python3 para trabajar con unos datos GPS recibidos por UART. Esos datos los tengo que castear y dejarlos preparados para posteriormente trabajar con ellos.

Sin embargo, me encuentro con la duda de cómo hacerlo, pues en un principio había tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
def gga_read(data_in):

    tmp = data_in.replace("*", ",")
    data_out = tmp.split(",")

    if len(data_out[1]) == 0:
        data_out[1] = 123456
        print("Datos no válidos. Muestra valor genérico.")
    else:
        data_out[1] = float(data_out[1])

return data_out
```

Funcionar, funciona, pero no sé si sería la mejor manera de hacerlo para cada uno de los elementos de la lista con los que tengo que trabajar (habría que hacer más de un if else o try except). De todas formas, he probado a hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
def gga_read(data_in):
    tmp = data_in.replace("*", ",")
    data_out = tmp.split(",")
    '''  Cast de elementos del vector y mensajes de error  '''

    try:
        data_out[1] = float(data_out[1])
    except ValueError:
        print("Datos hora UTC no válidos. Se aplicará un valor genérico de 123456")
        data_out[1] = 123456

return data_out
```

Entonces, la duda es cómo proceder para que el código sea mejor. Pues no sé si hacerlo con if else, excepciones u otra forma mejor. ¿Qué me sugerís?

Comment: En este caso particular la excepción parece más adecuada, pues tu "validación" es demasiado simple. La conversión a float puede fallar por otras razones que no hayas contemplado, como que haya caracteres no-digito, etc.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No había caído en eso de que pudiera ser que llegara algo que no fuera un número. De hecho, supongo que por los cables, al probarlo me llegó una string rara y lo filtró sin mayor problema y el código siguió ejecutándose